# 8-ball: is it a foul if the shooter doesn't touch the call shot ball?

Tags: rules, pool

I'm not sure if this is covered by the [6.2 Wrong Ball First](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=121&pagetype=rules#6.2). Basically I want to know if it's a foul in this case/example:

- the shooter is assigned the stripes group
- the shooter calls the shot: ball 13 and the head right pocket
- the shooter fails to touch the ball 13 but doesn't commit any other foul (e.g. the [6.3 No Rail after Contact](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=121&pagetype=rules#6.3), maybe hits another striped ball)

So in this case the shooter committed a foul and the opponent gets the cue ball in the hand or the shooter only lost his turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understanding of this rule seems to be right, except for one minor detail. Here is the rule in question, in its entirety (emphasis mine)

> **6.3 No Rail after Contact**
>
> ***If no ball is pocketed on a shot, the cue ball must contact an object ball***, and after that contact at least one ball (cue ball or any object ball) must be driven to a rail, or the shot is a foul.

If the shooter fails to make contact with the intended striped ball, the ball **MUST** go on to touch another striped ball and one of the balls must make contact with a rail, otherwise the shot is a foul and the opponent gets the ball in hand. In case the cue ball makes first contact with another striped ball and one of the balls makes contact with a rail, the player simply loses his turn.

Comment: That's exactly what I thinking but I wanted to be sure! Thanks!